# How to check whether LCD display is available or not in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, display

I want to know whether my LCD display is available or not, in embedded Linux.

How to do this check using some command?

If my display is not available does that affects my boot process?

Thank You

Comment: "or not in embedded Linux. " What do you mean with this? Ubuntu is not an embedded system.

Comment: @Rinzwind I mean available or not, in my embedded Linux.